# Compilation error: "error MSB3774: Could not find SDK "Microsoft.VCLibs, Version=11.0""

Tags: c++, windows-8, direct3d

I am trying to begin the Direct3D tutorial at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780567.aspx.

I created my new project, and the first part of the tutorial at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh780569.aspx says that you can just go ahead and build it, but when I build I get the following error.

`error MSB3774: Could not find SDK "Microsoft.VCLibs, Version=11.0"`

I've looked around, and I've found a little bit about the error, but nothing that's helped me actually get it working.

does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your SDK is corrupt. Try doing SDK repair, that will most likely solve your problem.

Comment: I've already tried something like that.  I went programs, found that i did not have "windows software development kit" so I installed it, and the problem persisted.  I then tried to repair it, and the problem persisted.

Comment: I don't mind your -1. I have been digging for an better answer for you, I'll update my answer when I have something. BTW, what version of Windows 8 you are running (RC)?

Comment: Just try reinstalling whole dev environment man, I just tried same sample and worked fine for me.

Comment: @SamIam shakehar is saying that "Repairing visual studio worked for him", you should try the same

Answer (score 2):

There are apparently a couple of ways to see this issue. One is, if you upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 8 after you've installed Visual Studio 2012. This is described in [KB2738090](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2738090), "You cannot build a C++ application for Windows Store after you upgrade to Visual Studio 2012 and upgrade from Windows 7 to Windows 8" (apt, isn't it). Answer: Repair your VS 2012 install.

The other way is if you install Visual Studio 2012 Update 1, and some confluence of stars causes some of the core library to be uninstalled. If your `%Program Files%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0\extensionsdks\microsoft.vclibs` directory has gone missing, you may find as I did that no amount of repair, removal, and replacing of VS or the Windows SDK can bring it back.

A little sleuthing led me to a couple of registry keys that appeared to be preventing the core library from being reinstalled:

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\VC\Libraries\Core\ArchNeutral\PaddedVersion`

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\VC\Libraries\Core\x86\PaddedVersion`

When I set both these REG_SZ values to "0" instead of "51106" and then reinstalled VS 2012 update 1, the extension SDKs for the core libraries returned, and I could once again build C++ Windows Store apps.

Perhaps this will help someone else who lands here after some searching for this apparently rare problem.

Answer (score 0):

This type of error usually means you might be trying to build without either specifying the architecture in the build configuration or having one selected that is not compatible with your setup.

Try setting the architecture to something other than 'any' in the Build->Configuration Manager.